# Change UPS batteries capacity and quantities

Tags: ups

Dears,

Im no expert and need your advise if what I'm having in mind is possible or not.
I own (MGE Pulsar Evo 3000) UPS that uses #6# batteries 12v / 7Amp the UPS is powerful for sure but the backup time is not that good.

Is it possible to reduce the quantity of the batteries to #1# or #2# or #4# for example 12v / 100Amp or 12v /300Amp ?

what do I need to have this done if possible ?

Notes : 
- I don't know the charger Amp of the UPS.
- Picture of the UPS ( [image: MGE Pulsar Evo 3000]

Comment: I doubt this is possible. The system will be designed for a specific type and capacity of battery. You'd probably have to reprogram any microcontrollers in the system as well as ensure the wiring of the system was capable of reliably handling the different load.

Comment: The UPS can potentially be used with a computer, but redesigning it has nothing to do with computers or software.

Answer (score 3):

I found an [online manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1020526/Mge-Ups-Systems-Pulsar-Evolution-3000-Xl.html#manual) for your UPS unit. The manual specifications show that the six batteries are connected in series. This means that the system voltage requirement is a nominal 72vdc.

You would not be able to reduce the number of batteries unless you have access to a 72vdc battery pack.

The other important piece of data from the manual specifies a maximum of 216 ampere-hour capacity. This means that the six batteries you select should have a capacity of no greater than 216 ampere-hours each. If you do not use such a super-large capacity battery, see below.

The diagram for this device also shows the circuit being able to accept parallel-series strings. If you have, for example, twelve batteries, connect them in strings of six, then parallel the two strings.

Keep all batteries in one string with the same ampere-hour capacity. You could, for example, have a string of 6 batteries, 12vdc, 10 ah and another string of 6 with 20 ah capacity. That would give you 30 ah capacity, well below the maximum of 216 ah noted in the manual.

The result of this type of connection will be increased back-up time.

Answer (score 2):

> 12v / 7Amp the UPS is powerful for sure but the backup time is not that good.

voltage and amper has nothing to do with how long it can provide energy. They tell you how quick they can deliver.

What's important for you is the capacity (9 AH), that tells how "much" energy your UPS has.

> Is it possible to reduce the quantity of the batteries to #1# or #2# or #4#

Why do you think manufacturer has not designed well the device and you can make a significant improvement by replacing batteries? Very likely it's not the case. If you need more service time, you need to buy a bigger UPS.