# Throubleshooting UPS

Tags: ups

I recently rescued an MGE 2200 VA UPS. The UPS has the batteries dead (extremely dead), as it has only 0.5V out of 72V (6x12V). Obviously, it has been unplugged for a while.

When I plug the UPS to the wall (with or without the battery connected). It refuses to turn on. No LEDs come up, no relay sound, nothing. Inspecting the PCBs, I found a corroded trace, which I have bridged, with no effect on the UPS's behavior.

I've read on some forums that this is normal, they refuse to turn up unless a valid battery is in place. However I am not willing to expend money on 6 batteries just to test whether this hypothesis is true or not. 
my question is about how I can test it. I have a working 2x12V battery pack from my current UPS. However, I'm afraid that if I plug them in, they might get damaged. Furthermore, 24V might not be sufficient. Another thing I've thought about is trying to charge those 6 dead batteries, in groups of 2 with my current UPS.

Do you recommend any of these 2 tests? What other alternative can I try?

Edit: the UPS seems to have been manufactured in 2002. Manual of the UPS: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/467056/Mge-Ups-Systems-Pulsar-Evolution-2200.html?page=8#manual

Edit2: What's the brand reputation of MGE, it seems like now its property of Eaton. My current UPS is from Eaton, although linux recognizes it as a MGE UPS. It has served me OK for the last 2 years

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1306951/change-ups-batteries-capacity-and-quantities?rq=1 this is a 3000 VA variant of the same UPS. It seems like the first test **CANNOT** be done

Comment: The UPS can be used with a computer, among other things, but troubleshooting or servicing it isn't a computer hardware or software question.

Comment: Most UPSes are designed to power on and deliver utility power in the absence of working batteries. I submit as evidence that UPSes can report dead or failing batteries, something only possible if they can operate with dead or failing batteries. Thus I would be suspicious the UPS's failure is not due to the batteries.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator. I've tested my current UPS pulling out it's battery and above mentioned behavior occurs. Although it keeps running if the batteries were pulled out while powered on, it refuses to turn after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Smart charging technology needs to see battery voltage first to turn on, and what you read is correct - my last UPS had issues exactly as yours.  Below a design threshold minimum, it will not turn on at all.   You could try to take each battery out of the UPS to try and charge separately [using on old school "dumb" charger] to see which ones will hold a charge, but as dead as that system is... just replace them all.    I replace my UPS batteries every 4 years, as problems are almost guaranteed at the 5 year mark, and it's money well spent.  What caused me to replace my entire UPS before?  The control board failed, and [of course] the OEM had stopped supplying that replacement part.  Your corrosion problem is likely survivable if no other problems are found.  As for other batteries you want to try... do they have the same rating [amp-hours] and will they supply the same voltage?  Both need to be correct.  I have seen charging setups where somebody went oversized on battery capacity and everything was fine, until batteries began to age - it burned up the charger because current demand was too high.  Stick with the OEM rating [wherever you buy batteries from].  Per page 25 of the manual you need six 12v batteries each rated at 7aH - take measurements if needed to make sure you get the right form factor when replacing, and diagram jumper wire connections if you feel you need it.